# Ordinal number plus superlative adjective

Tags: gf

In the RGL, `Ord` is a type which represents either an ordinal number (in words or digits):

```
mkOrd : Numeral -> Ord --“twenty-second”
mkOrd : Digits -> Ord  --“22nd”
```

Or a superlative adjective:

```
mkOrd : A -> Ord       --“smallest”
```

But not both.

What if I *do* want both though, like “(Tampere is the) second largest (city in Finland)”?

Or is there a way somewhere further up the tree that I can combine two `Ord` into a single `Det`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, it's just not in the API. There's a function in [Noun.gf](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/abstract/Noun.gf#L80) called `OrdNumeralSuperl : Numeral -> A -> Ord`, and you can use it by opening `NounXxx` in your concrete syntax, as follows:

```hs
resource Test = open SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng, (N=NounEng) in {
  oper

    myTest : NP = mkNP (mkDet the_Quant second_largest_Ord) (mkN "city") ;

    second_largest_Ord : Ord = N.OrdNumeralSuperl (mkNumeral "2") (mkA "large") ;
}
```

And you can see the result as follows:

```
$ gf
> i -retain Test.gf
- compiling Test.gf...   write file Test.gfo
> cc -one myTest
the second largest city
```